# issue with nginx regex

Tags: nginx

want to write a regex rule in nginx which returns 410 for files ending with .html extension and at the same time want to exclude certain urls from that rule and return 301 for them so how can i accomplish the same please help

Comment: Please provide a full example of what you have tried so far and explain, why it didn't satisfy your needs.

Comment: hi  i have added a location block rule to return a 410 for all files ending in html and in that specified rewrite rule fro 301 redirect fro urls